# Creating matrix out of an array of categories in numpy

Tags: numpy

I have a length-n numpy array, y, of integers in the range [0...k-1]. From this, I would like to create an n-by-k numpy matrix M, where M[i,j] is 1 if y[i]==j, and 0 else.

What is the best way to do this in numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use broadcasting:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0])
m = a[:, None] == np.arange(max(a)+1)
```

the result is:

```
array([[False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Or create a zero array and fill, I think it's faster:

```
m2 = np.zeros((len(a), a.max()+1), np.bool)
m2[np.arange(len(a)), a] = True
print m2
```

Comment: I think your second suggestion nails it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe a bit out there, but its a pretty extensible solution and at least worth noting. If you've already got [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html), the [`DictVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer) class is used to transform categorical features in a dataset to column-wise binary representations just like you described:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer

# starting with your numpy array
y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0])

# transform the array to a list of dicts, with original
# int values now as strings, and a throw-away key '' 
y_dict = [{'':str(x)} for x in y.tolist()]

# create the vectorizer and transform the list of dicts 
vec = DictVectorizer(sparse=False, dtype=int)
M = vec.fit_transform(y_dict)

print M
[[0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0]]
```

Again, probably overkill but it's kind of cute and I thought I'd throw it out there.